# Make an instant effect when injecting CSS

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have this:

`script.js`:

```
function addStyleString(str) {
    var node = document.createElement('style');
    node.innerHTML = str;
    document.body.appendChild(node);
}
var test = 'html {'
    test += '    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/eWtfMME.png");'
    test += '    background-repeat: repeat;'
    test += '}'
addStyleString(test);
```

and `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "testtt",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "3.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://mywebsite.com"],
      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

It's working, but it injects everything just after the webpage is loaded. How can I make the effect just instant? Just like the [*Stylish* webextension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=de) does.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `run_at` `document_start`

There are multiple ways to do it.  Assuming you want to continue to use a *manifest.json* `content_script` entry, the thing to do is have your `content_script` entry be [`run_at`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at)<sup><sup>([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts#run_at))</sup></sup> `document_start`:

```json
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://mywebsite.com/*"],
      "js": ["script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
```

If your JavaScript is running at `document_start`, you will need to append the `<style>` to the `document.documentElement`, as the `head` and `body` do not exist, yet, at that time.

Note: You have an error in your match pattern which prevents the extension from loading. Match patterns must specify a path. I have added `/*` to your `matches`.

#### For static styles, use a `css` entry

However, if you are just adding static CSS, it would be better to move the CSS into a separate *.css* file and have that automatically loaded through a `content_scripts` [`css`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#css)<sup><sup>([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts#css))</sup></sup> entry:

*manifest.json*:

```json
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://mywebsite.com/*"],
      "js": ["script.js"],
      "css": ["myStaticStyles.css"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
```

*myStaticStyles.css*:

```css
html {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/eWtfMME.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    /*Added background-color because your image is dark. This helps there not be as much
      of a flash of the normal white new-tab background while waiting for your image to
      display. */
    background-color: black; 

}
```

#### Asynchronous nature of network requests

Particularly because you are using a `background-image` to a network URL, there is a delay between when the CSS is inserted into the DOM and when the image is displayed.  This is caused by there being a delay between Chrome recognizing that the URL needs to be fetched and when the data is available. You can shorten this by using a less complex image, re-encoding the image to be smaller, or [converting the image to a data URL](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/), as suggested by wOxxOm in comments.

If your issue is that there is a `background-image` in the site you are trying to override which loads faster than your image, you can do a few possible things that will prevent it from loading:

- Modify the HTML of the page to temporarily remove the element that is loading the other CSS with a different `background-image`. You can re-insert the element once your image is loaded. You may need to use a `webRequest` listener to determine when your image has completed loading. Once it has, you can re-insert the element responsible for the other `background-image`.
- Use a [`webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) listener to cancel the request for the URL of the other background-image. Depending on *exactly* what you are wanting to do, you may need to use thing in combination with a content script and/or a `webNavigation` listener.
- Modify the CSS that is being loaded into the page to eliminate the other `background-image`. Depending on how the CSS is being applied, this can be complex and difficult, but is possible.

Comment: I've just realized I shouldn't use `run_at: document_start`, because it prevents me from loading the entire css. Using the `content_script` works, but is there a way to prevent showing the default background before MY background?!

Comment: @kraky222, I'm not sure why it prevents you from loading the complete CSS. Please explain why that is the case. If it is that some of your CSS is dynamic and depends on the content of the page, there is nothing preventing you from loading two, or more, portions of CSS. For instance, one portion that is static and loads at `document_start` and another that is dynamic and is loaded by JavaScript as soon as the elements are available.

Comment: @kraky222 - I'm happy to help, but you are asking detailed questions for which more context is needed. I *can't* answer them without being able to duplicate the issue. To be able to answer I'm going to need enough code to duplicate the issue and a link to the exact URL on which which you are testing.

Comment: thanks. I've noticed that when I apply a simple `"run at": "document_start"` no image shows, but by clicking "inspect the page" I can see it's injected as a style: `<style>html {    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/eWtfMME.png");    background-repeat: repeat;}</style>`. Note that I've changed in the first code shown in OP the `document.body.appendChild(node);` instruction with `document.documentElement.appendChild(node);` to get at least this effect in the page's source. why does it do this effect!?!

Comment: @kraky222, this doesn't seem to be related to document_start in particular. It's possible Chrome enqueues the image in the overall page load process so it's retrieved after something else. See if the same userstyle is applied immediately by Stylish extension. Try different background-image urls, different images. Be pro-active, work the angles.

Comment: @wOxxOm hey, you are right. It's not an image proble, I've tried again. I've tried in Firefox, the extension is working perfectly. Chrome seems to have this problem, but with Stylish this userstyle is working. How can I fix this?

Comment: Post a link to your extension zip here.

Comment: @wOxxOm why? Doesn't a copy-paste + zip to the OP's code work?

Comment: It's easier to reproduce using the exact extension you're using.

Comment: @wOxxOm it's just the same for any browser! :) I have a bad connection, so uploading would be bad for me. Couldn't you do it yourself please?

Comment: Eh? The zip file is 1kB at most.

Comment: I've tried on www.example.com and I see no difference between Stylish and the code copypasted from your question and this answer: both methods flicker the empty tab background in Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm I can't post the real link for some reasons, but I can sure this is the problem. Do you have anything to say regarding this? What may the problem be?

Comment: Apparently this is how Chrome handles images. You can alleviate this by setting a dark `background-color` first. Or by recompressing the image to make it smaller so it loads faster.

Comment: Or [convert the image to data URI](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) and embed it inside the style string.

Comment: @kraky222, It is not clear to me if your issue is to eliminate the flash of Chrome new-tab/new-page default-color that happens for basically all new tabs or that the `backgound-image` supplied in the page is displaying for a time. As I initially requested, we need to be able to duplicate the issue you are having. We need the URL for the web page you are testing and a description of **exactly** what the issue is (what is flashing, how that differs from loading any other page).

Comment: @kraky222, Stylish does not have any special access to be able to load things earlier. What it is doing is going to be something near identical to what is shown here. If your use of Stylish shows an actual difference, then we are going to need the **exact** Stylish configuration that you are using, and, again, the URL on which you are actually applying the changes.